# Writing a macro for a spreadsheet in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I need to write a spreadsheet which when you press a button adds a row of data and asks for the parameters needed for the calculations, but I cant seem to get it right, its really frustrating me, any help would be appreciated. I am a complete begginner to macros in excel and have only done very basic programming for matlab on my uni course. My script so far is as follows:

```
Sub AddPosTol()
'
' AddPosTol Macro
'
   Dim rngSeek As Range

   Set rngSeek = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)

   With rngSeek.Offset(0, 1)
       With .Font
           .Name = "Solid Edge ANSI1 Symbols"
           .Size = 11
       End With
  End With
  Range(rngSeek).Offset(0, 1) = "l"
  Range(rngSeek).Offset(0, 3) = "=RC[-1]"
  Range(rngSeek).Offset(0, 4) = "0"

  With rngSeek.Offset(1, 1)
      With .Font
        .Bold = True
      End With
  End With

  Range(rngSeek).Offset(1, 1) = "X value"
  Range(rngSeek).Offset(2, 1) = "Y Value"

  Range(rngSeek).Offset(0, 4) = "=2*SQRT((R[1]C[-3]-R[1]C)^2+(R[2]C[-3]-R[2]C)^2)"
  Range(rngSeek).Offset(0, 5) = "=2*SQRT((R4C3-R[1]C)^2+(R5C3-R[2]C)^2)"
  Range(rngSeek).Offset(0, 6) = "=2*SQRT((R[1]C[-3]-R[1]C)^2+(R[2]C[-3]-R[2]C)^2)"
  Range(rngSeek).Offset(0, 7) = "=2*SQRT((R[1]C[-3]-R[1]C)^2+(R[2]C[-3]-R[2]C)^2)"
  Range(rngSee).Offset(0, 8) = "=2*SQRT((R4C3-R[1]C)^2+(R5C3-R[2]C)^2)"

  Range(rngSeek).Offset(0, 2) = (InputBox("Insert Positional Tolerance Diametre"))
  Range(rngSeek).Offset(1, 2) = (InputBox("Insert X value on drawing"))
  Range(rngSeek).Offset(2, 2) = (InputBox("Insert Y value on drawing"))

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined `rngSeek` as a range and then are trying to use that range definition with the `Range()` method of the worksheet.

All the lines where you have `Range(rngSeek).Offset(...` you can replace with `rngSeek.Offset(...`

(One of your formula also references the wrong cells ;-)

Comment: Okay thanks, yeah i suspected some of those formulas might be wrong as i started by recording the macro and then realised that wasn't going to work and have been editing it as i've been learning about vba.
I have done as you say with the rngseek, Ford some odd reason my excel seems to crash when i run it now?

Comment: The only other issue I can see is if you don't have a value in column A as this will cause problems with the `xlDown` and subsequent `Offsets`.   Otherwise, what exactly do you mean by crash since the code worked for me when the `rngSeek` problem was fixed.

Comment: It was a problem as I'd messed about with a loop instead of using the x1Down function, but i've changed that now and it works fine thanks. The only problem is now i have no idea how to write fomulas in the macro referencing the cells relative to themselves if you get me. As i know where the cells i want are going to be relative to the cell with fomula inside it but as that cell isnt neccessarily going to be in the same place i cant reference them like A1 ect.

Comment: You use relative formulas so I'm not quite sure what you mean.  You probably should close this question off a start a new one.

Comment: I worked it out by looking at the formulas but thanks, you right R[how much you want offset for the row]C[How much you want offset for the column]

Comment: That's great. If my answer fixed the problem would you consider accepting it?  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer.  Cheers.

Comment: Yeah sure, no idea how you do it but i'll give it a go

Comment: Thanks for that.  Good luck with your coding!